# Django: OperationalError when I try to create user from admin

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I have Django 1.10 with MySQL, every time I enter admin and I try to make a user I get this error:

[image]

The thing is I can create any other model and if I create a super user from command line I can edit that user but when I press "add user" I get this error. I tried deleting the database and making it again twice.

And here is my settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # our apps
    'authentication',
    'homepages',
    'school'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/templates/'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'isj',
        'USER': 'test_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',  # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
```

Comment: Could you please update you question with your settings.py?

Comment: There you have it :)

Comment: The line "Exception Value" says: "SAVEPOINT ... does not exist". This question could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13728843/293494

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've found out that the root cause is the `MySQL-Python` database driver and the fix is to use other MySQL drivers for Python (e.g. `mysqlclient`).

```
$ pip uninstall MySQL-Python
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

`MySQL-python` turned out to be very old (last commit was 7 years ago). `mysqlclient` is the modern version of it, with lots of improvements and bug fixes.

More details about my fix and findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003341/django-mysql-admin-site-add-user-error/#answer-45255643).