# Django + MySQL - Admin Site - Add User - OperationalError - SAVEPOINT does not exist

Tags: mysql, django, xampp, mysql-python, savepoints

We're trying to have a custom User model and behaviors, but then we noticed that even the **default Django installation** has issue when adding a new User via the Django Admin:

[image]

The issue happens even in other Django versions (tried it in Django **1.8**, and w/ the latest one, Django **1.11.3**). Surprisingly, the issue does not happen when using SQLite or PostgreSQL databases. Also, adding user via `$./manage.py createuser` and programmatically will work. Editing existing uses like the previously created `admin` superuser via terminal will also work. CRUD mechanisms for Group work as intended, hence only the `Add User` view is affected.

Possible point of failures include the **Django core** (any version), **MySQL binary** (bundled in XAMPP for Mac, tried various versions also), or the **MySQL-Python** connector (version 1.2.5). Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905738/django-operationalerror-when-i-try-to-create-user-from-admin), using Django **1.10** and MySQL.

Steps to replicate:

1. Install the latest Django version:
   `$ pip install django`
2. Install the Python-MySQL driver:
   `$ pip install MySQL-python`
3. Create a new project:
   `$ django-admin.py startproject sandbox`
4. Create a new database in MySQL and set the db config in `settings.py`
5. Migrate the Django apps' models:
   `$ ./manage.py migrate`
6. Create an `admin` superuser:
   `$ ./manage.py createsuperuser`
7. Run the Django's bundled server:
   `$ ./manage.py runserver`
8. Go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login`, and login w/ the `admin` superuser credentials.
9. Try clicking the **Users**' **Add** button. The attached error in screenshot will be triggered.

Sample Database Query Logs:

```
Query   SET NAMES utf8
Query   set autocommit=1
Query   SELECT `django_session`.`session_key`, `django_session`.`session_data`, `django_session`.`expire_date` FROM `django_session` WHERE (`django_session`.`session_key` = 'ikql6mk9voxq4g0go9avuvuxxrpvwx9w' AND `django_session`.`expire_date` > '2017-07-10 06:58:15.823513')
Query   SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`id` = 1
Query   SAVEPOINT `s123145414516736_x1`
Query   RELEASE SAVEPOINT `s123145414516736_x1`
Query   ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `s123145414516736_x1`
Query   rollback
Query   set autocommit=1
Quit
```

It seems that the SAVEPOINT ROLLBACK has been done after the SAVEPOINT RELEASE causing the SAVEPOINT to be missing. Based from [MySQL's SavePoint docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html), the natural order seems to be ROLLBACK then RELEASE.

Here's the Traceback messages. No other changes in Django's default `settings.py` except for the database config/credentials for connecting to MySQL server:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
  103.             return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in _add_view
  131.                                                extra_context)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1508.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1408.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in __exit__
  210.                                 connection.savepoint_rollback(sid)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in savepoint_rollback
  348.         self._savepoint_rollback(sid)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in _savepoint_rollback
  308.             cursor.execute(self.ops.savepoint_rollback_sql(sid))

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  63.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/Users/ranelpadon/.virtualenvs/django__1_11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/add/
Exception Value: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s123145452511232_x1 does not exist')
```

Comment: I think there is some IntegrityError. Enable logging and check.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I've tried enabling the MySQL logs and got more info:

Comment: I've edited the post also to include the MySQL logs and emphasize the SAVEPOINT workflow/order inconsistency. Could be a bug in Django core.

Comment: I've found that this can happen on clustered MySQL/Maria Db instances - maybe replication is slow between slaves?

Answer (score 7):

This bug haunted me for a long time, so I decided to dig further and try to resolve it once and for all.

Root Cause: The SAVEPOINT issue is a bug that occurs only in `MySQL-Python` connector.

Fix:
Use other MySQL drivers for Python (e.g. `mysqlclient`).

Details/Findings:

- Tried the MySQL binaries in Homebrew, MAMP, and XAMPP for Mac.
- Tried various MySQL versions, 5.6 (`libmysqlclient.18.dylib`) and 5.7    (`libmysqlclient.20.dylib`).
- Tried various Python's MySQL drivers.

No relationships found by varying the MySQL binaries/versions. But I've narrowed down the issue by testing various MySQL drivers commonly used in Python:

1. **MySQLdb** (widely-used but old database connector, last commit was 7 years ago!):

   `$ pip install MySQL-python`
2. **mysqlclient** (modern version of `MySQL-python`, but w/ lots of bug fixes and improvements):

   `$ pip install mysqlclient`
3. **PyMySQL** (pure Python MySQL database driver):

   `$ pip install PyMySQL`

   Then, add in `settings.py` (just below the `import os`):

   ```
   try:
       import pymysql
       pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   except:
       pass
   ```
4. **MySQL-Connector-Python** by Oracle (pure Python MySQL database driver):

   `$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`

   Then, edit the database's `ENGINE` configuration in `settings.py`:

   ```
   'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
   ```

The SAVEPOINT issue occurs only when using the **MySQL-python** connector (#1 driver), but not in the others (#2, #3, #4 drivers). On my case, I had chosen the **mysqlclient**. Issue is gone now.

Comment: I am seeing what looks exactly like this error with mysqlclient 1.4.2.post1

Comment: same problem with `mysqlclient 1.4.6`

Comment: also have this issue with `mysqlclient==2.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by overriding `UserAdmin`. It seems like there is a problem with nested atomic transactions in clustered DBs.

Add the following lines to the Custom UserAdmin which inherits from base Django UserAdmin:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters_m
@csrf_protect_m
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a project that was just upgraded from python 2 to 3 and this happened because I installed `mysqlclient` and that's what caused that (on python 3.5) taken from one of the suggestions above:

```
$ pip install PyMySQL

in settings.py added:

try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass
```