# Django nested transaction.atomic throw IntegrityError "SAVEPOINT does not exist" with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing, transactions

I am trying to make nested `transaction.atomic()` work. The following block of code crashes when exiting first `transaction.atomic()` with the following error `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s4568333760_x1 does not exist')`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from django.db import transaction

class FooTest(TransactionTestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with transaction.atomic():
            with transaction.atomic():
                u = User.objects.create_user(username="abc", password="pass")
                print("created user: {}".format(u.username))
```

It seems like this happens due to the fact that Django fails to execute `TRANSACTION START` or `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` during the test. I know this by looking at local MySQL query log.

Of course, my final test is not that simple, but the following example shows the concept which should work by does not.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug of Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's a bug in mysqlclient I am using. After a lot of digging, I was able to narrow it down and find the following answer on StackOverflow.

TL;DR This is being resolved by using different version of SQL connector. In my case, I was using *mysqlclient* and switched to *PyMySQL* which solved the problem.

[Django + MySQL - Admin Site - Add User - OperationalError - SAVEPOINT does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003341/django-mysql-admin-site-add-user-operationalerror-savepoint-does-not-e/45255643#45255643)